# How to convince my boss to use symfony 2 instead of 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony, symfony-plugins

For our next project we will be using symfony framework.
I would like to use Symfony 2 because it's new, modern and future-looking.
On the other hand my boss prefers the older version because of a big number of plugins (in Sf2 these are bundles and I guess are not yet very numerous). 
Nevertheless I would opt for sf2.
Question is how to reason with my boss ;)

Comment: Wht are his arguments aginst? You say you want to, he says he doesn't..?

Comment: You forgot `cool` in the sf2 adjectives...   Seriously, it may be an uphill battle because a) there are `many compelling reasons` to stick with sf1.4 for some time, particularly in a business environment and b) if the quality of your question is an indication about your capacity to persuade... ;-)

Comment: If you rephrase this as a question on the technical merits of the two platforms rather than being about your boss, it would be acceptable on [programmers.se].

Comment: @MichaelMyers This is not just a question of technical merit. The question here is whether Symfony2 is ready to be relied on for a production site.

Answer (score 6):

1. This is not a programming problem, it's office politics, ask it at http://programmers.stackexchange.com.
2. I agree with your boss, you should be using the stable, documented framework that hundreds or thousands of other developers have used and have written information about. You should not be using a week old framework with no community, half-written documentation and little real world testing at your business.

You can use Symfony 2 for your pet projects at home until it matures. "New,  modern and future-looking" are **negative** qualifiers when choosing business solutions.

Comment: +1. You absolutely need to build something reasonably complex for yourself in Symfony2 first. When you say "you guess" that Bundles are not yet very numerous for Symfony2, you show that you've not done enough research yourself :)

Comment: Office politics questions are off topic on Programmers.

Answer (score 2):

- Symfony 2 is  [about 3 times faster than 1.4](http://symfony.com/six-good-technical-reasons#fast)
- It will have a longer support life
- Ongoing, will likely be easier to get support for 2.0

Comment: The -1 (not mine) was maybe a bit severe, but you have 3 dots and only 2, maybe 2.5 effective points...  one of which (performance/scalability) is possibly not a big selling factor given sf1.4 proven ability to serve rather well many mid-size applications and the other (support) which is at once rather self evident but also possibly desingenious given the much broader support network/community afforded to sf1.4 ATM.